# python 64 bit, multiprocessing is not utilizing max

Tags: python, multiprocessing

facing a problem utilizing the processor cores for maximum using multiprocessing on 64-bit python.

There are 2 places in the code where I have multiprocessing. The code is actually quite resource-intensive. I've tried using "map" function on the processors' pool as per documentation with simple code samples and it used to kinda work, I saw processor utilization spikes going to 99%. This one, though, is keeping at around 20%, it uses all the cores, but somehow it not "pushing" to max. For the moment it's running for around 24 hours having this low utilization. Obviously, there is a lot of computational work to do, but something is keeping it at low pace. Seems like Windows may be controlling it (I have no other soft running on the server though). What can it be?

```
    with Pool() as p: # should calculate the number of processors automatically
         p.map(fdas_and_digitize, Reports)
```

and

```
    with Pool() as p: # should calculate the number of processes automatically
    # put permutations of 2 reports there
         p.map(PnL, files_periods) # this executes in parallel now
```

There is an average of 260 python processes in the memory at once (they finish and new ones are created).

Here's the full source code
https://pastebin.com/PnPFUxeL

Windows Server 2016, 64 bit, 24 cores

C:\Users\Administrator>python --version
Python 3.7.1

[image]

Comment: That seems like a lot of processes given that you have 48 logical processors. You mention that the resource intensive. Does that mean resources like disk files or internet access? If you are accessing disk files or the internet, then the process may be limited by those resources, CPU utilization is only one measure of how much work is being done.

Comment: well, it does not use the internet and I/O is about initially reading files from disk, them adding data to Redis, doing calculations, and then writing results to MySQL. The thing is I'd like it to work faster by utilizing 99% of processors, not 20%. That was the whole idea for renting this powerful machine.

Comment: Are you certain the processes do not hit any locks? Profile your code and post the results.

Comment: Typically, multiprocessing is slowed by the locks that @LukaszTracewski mentioned. Perhaps `redis` or `MySQL` is limiting concurrent access. That would result in your processes waiting for access and reducing your CPU utilization. I am not an expert in either of those applications, but that is where I would start looking.

Comment: all correct guys, I've re-coded the thing with vectorized blocks on numpy, ufuncs, removed redis and IO, now utilization is 99%. Thank you!